# How to create a custom user login account page where user can upload papers that stores in mysql database?

Tags: mysql, web, servlets, web-development-server

Suppose i've already made a Dynamic page using sessions in servlet that generates a user login page and in that account if User has uploaded paper in his own account, after he logs in again , that should be there already.

How can we stored image in database, and how can we transfer image to another account also known to be reviewer that gets to be review the paper uploaded by user
in his account.

How can this be possible, Anyone please help me, Because i have no idea, i am studying Servlets right now. Please Help. Thanks

Comment: You really want to avoid writing your own login system because these things are very easy to get wrong, to accidentally create something that's not a security layer, but an injection point for someone to attack your system. Remember, always, **always** use a password-specific hash like [Bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) for your passwords. Users are trusting you with their personal data, so take this responsibility seriously.

Comment: its a small assignment/project that will be implemented on a Apache local host, as i am not developing and deploying my site @tadman

Comment: If it's an academic project it's still worth doing it the right way as Bcrypt isn't hard to use and provides a lot of concrete benefits. Good habits go a long way in this business. Bad habits learned out of laziness or lack of knowing better cause immeasurable damage.

Comment: @tadman is there any way to do this ?, i will take care of attacks ..

Comment: This question is arguably too broad because there's no code given for context so it's hard to say what the problem is and how you might go about fixing it. Images are stored in the database how? What do you mean by review? A lot of this becomes clear when there's code to have a look at.

Comment: HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.getAttribute("email"+email); @tadman

Comment: @tadman this is a snippet code from my servlet which is used to track session data(username) after he successfully logs on in which creates a dynamic web page but now , is it its account page to upload paper or how can i do that one?

Comment: While that is technically code, it's not nearly enough to go on. What does email have to do with images stored in a database?

Comment: If you really don't know where to start or need guidance or support consider mentoring and coaching services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com). These are much more interactive and can involve screen-sharing to walk through your problem and work towards a working solution.

Comment: I could show you in a proper way if i get to know how to insert images in this comment box ? @tadman

Comment: Images are the worst way to present code, comments are the second worst. Just edit your question to include more code if necessary. That makes it much easier to read and follow.

Comment: @tadman are those services free ?

Comment: @tadman and which one includes screen sharing, is it the same like remote connection to pc ?

Comment: @tadman its okay

Comment: This question is too broad. You haven't even provided any code showing that you have actually done some of your own research and put some effort into this.